# Lower bound on sum of reciprocal primes

Tags: prime-numbers, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem, distribution-of-primes

What is the best known lower bound for 
$$\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p}?$$
The best one I found was
$$\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p} \ge B + \ln{\ln{x}} - \left(\frac{1}{10\ln ^2 x} + \frac{4}{15\ln ^3 x}\right),$$
extracted from [Pierre Dusart's "Sharper bounds for $\psi, \theta, \pi, p_k$](http://public.gettysburg.edu/~dglass/spring04/chebyshev.pdf)."

Has anyone made any improvement on it since then?

Thank you!